# reference request

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

Can anybody help me to find the books on numerical solutions of partial differential equations including examples on irregular geometry (specially books or links on matlab code examples in this case)?

Comment: Check Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method by Claes Johnson.

Comment: You might try this question on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/